# Covariance of estimated sample mean in Mixed Models

Tags: regression, mixed-model, estimation, covariance

For example, if I have the normal mixed model: $ \text{E} (y_{ij}) = \mu + a_{i}$ with $i = 1,...,N$, $j = 1,...,n$ and $a_{i}$ are independent $N(0, \sigma_{i}^2)$.

I know that: $$\text{Cov}(\hat{\mu}) = \frac{\sigma^2 + n \sigma_a^2}{Nn}$$

But I can't find the proof anywhere, nor I've been able to do it.

Is this analogous in any way to the Standard Error formula, or am I having the wrong idea about how mixed models work?

$$\text{Var}(\hat{\mu}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n},$$

How can I prove that covariance and how should I proceed to find an estimate for it?

Comment: What is $\text{Cov}(\hat{\mu})$?  A covariance is between two things not one, and you haven't defined what $\hat{\mu}$ is supposed to be.

Comment: @dsaxton The meaning of $\hat \mu$ is evident from the context--a mixed model that has been clearly specified--and the natural meaning of "Cov" when applied to a one-dimensional parameter is that it's the variance.